# 2 breakers connected together

Tags: electrical

I have two 20 amp breakers connected together with nothing else connected to those breakers. I have not had the electricity turned on but I am wondering why this was a done and what would happen if the electric was turned on and these two Breakers was still connected together?

Comment: Please edit your question are you saying you have a two pole breaker or is one circuit feeding through two different breakers? Maybe a picture would be nice.

Comment: If you mean the wires are connected to each other, they will trip.  If you mean the breakers have [**handle-ties**](https://www.electricalsupplies.com/ProductDetail.asp?InventorySys=981892), those have a very specific purpose and they are required. To understand why requires a relatively deep understanding of this field.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to presume that you mean the handles of the breakers are tied together.

This is the older method of creating a 2 pole, 240 volt circuit or a multiwire branch circuit.

If nothing is connected to them then nothing will happen when you turn them on.

Comment: It could be several other things.  There are several areas in modern usage where handle-ties are required. Some of them are not easy to explain but still important.  A simple one: if you split a receptacle and feed it from 2 circuits, they must be handle-tied so a repairman is forced to turn them off as a pair. (so he doesn't turn off one circuit and unexpectedly get bit by the other one).